# remove ManyToMany from model but still access data

Tags: python, django

I'm a DJANGO/python novice and I have two models Enqueue and EnqueueGroup.

Enqueue has a M2M field:

```
groups = models.ManyToManyField(
        "EnqueueGroup",
        related_name="Enqueued",
        blank=True,
    )
```

if I remove the *groups* field from the Enqueue model, what do I need to do in order to access the data formerly in *groups* if EnqueueGroups is currently as follows

```
class EnqueueGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
    )

    description = models.TextField(
        null=True, blank=True
    )

    class Meta:
        app_label = "test"
        verbose_name = "Enqueue Group"
        verbose_name_plural = "Enqueue Groups"

    def __str__(self):
        return "Enqueue Group {}".format(self.name)
```

read through the DJANGO M2M and relational database docs. I understand that the relation is called *groups* in Enqueue and *Enqueued* in EnqueueGroup. I just dont /get/ how to still access the data.

Comment: If you look in the database, there will be an additional table, likely `enqueue_enqueue_group` which contains the IDs from the related tables. However, if you were yo remove the `groups` field and run the migrations, the it is likely that the related data is lost. You can of course run `makemigrations` and see what the new migration does without actually running the `migrate` command.